# Pandas groupby - when column is a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by, count

For the following table:

[image]

I would like to use the groupby function with 'number_of_horses' and show a count for the 'TRUE' values in the 'winner' column.

Using Python-Pandas, I have tried:

INPUT:

```py
df.groupby('number_of_horses').winner.count()
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

The table above is not the desired output.

The desired output is:

[image]

Note that the 'winner' column is only counted when the value is TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df[df.winner == True].groupby('number_of_horses').winner.count().reset_index()
```

Output

```
   number_of_horses  winner
0                 2       2
1                 3       6
```

If the `winner` column is a string, then use `df.winner == "TRUE"` as your filtering criteria